# How can i position absolutely a div which contains a youtube video with <object> tag in my website?

Tags: html, css, youtube, position, absolute

i would like to import a youtube video in my website.

I'm using  the object code as you'll see later on.
I have two divs. Each of them is positioned absolutely (position:absolute).

My problem is that the div2 which containes the youtube coding ""
 doesn't "obey" to z-index attribute.

I would like the **div2** which **contains the youtube video** ****to be overlapped by div1**** which has a z-index: 3 greater than z-index(div2):1.

My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">

.div1 {
    width:540px;
    height:400px;
        border:3px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
}

.div2 {
    width:540px;
    height:350px;
    border:3px solid blue;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="div2">

    <object width="540" height="415" >
     <param name="movie"
         value="http://www.youtube.com/v/NWHfY_lvKIQ?version=3&autohide=1&showinfo=0"></param>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/NWHfY_lvKIQ?version=3&autohide=1&showinfo=0"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         allowscriptaccess="always"
         width="540" height="415"></embed>
</object>

</div>
<div class="div1">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

If you run the example, you 'll see that div2 overlaps div1 and it shouldn't.
I think that the problem is with the code

How can i solve this problem?Have you ever faced this problem again?

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the wmode to transparent so this will work.  Check this :

http://jsfiddle.net/XjyHk/

Comment: Well as i can see it's fine now in my program! Thank you!